# Golang, what does the following do []

Tags: arrays, go, composite-literals

I'm new to golang and have a basic question.  I have the following code taken from an example from the web

```
func (d Direction) String() string {
    return [...]string{"North", "East", "South", "West"}[d]
}
```

I'm confused what does the `[d]` do in the method body?

Comment: Going through the complete [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/) might help establish the language fundamentals.

Answer (score 5):

`[d]` is simply an [index expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions), it indexes the [array](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Array_types) created with a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) preceding it.

This:

```
[...]string{"North", "East", "South", "West"}
```

Is an array composite literal, it creates an array of element type `string` with the listed elements, and the subsequent `[d]` indexes this array. The method returns the `d`<sup>th</sup> element of this 4-sized array.

Note that the `...` means we want the compiler to determine the array size automatically:

> The notation `...` specifies an array length equal to the maximum element index plus one.

Arrays in Go is not to be mistaken with [slices](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types). For a good introduction on arrays and slices, read the official blog posts:

[The Go Blog: Go Slices: usage and internals](https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro)

[The Go Blog: Arrays, slices (and strings): The mechanics of 'append'](https://blog.golang.org/slices)

Answer (score 3):

This part declares an array literal with four strings:

```
[...]string{"North", "East", "South", "West"}
```

Then this part gets the `d`th element from the array:

```
[...]string{"North", "East", "South", "West"}[d]
```

`Direction` has to be `int` for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

@icza and @Burak Serdar have mentioned that [d] is an index expression.

Following is just a working example to see the output

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Direction int

func (d Direction) String() string {
    return [...]string{"North", "East", "South", "West"}[d]
}

func main() {
    n:=Direction(0)  // d=0
    fmt.Println(n)
    w:=Direction(3)  // d=3
    fmt.Println(w)
}
```

Output:

```
North
West
```

To be more clear,

`return [...]string{"North", "East", "South", "West"}[d]`

can be expanded as

```
func (d Direction) String() string {
    var directions = [...]string{"North", "East", "South", "West"}
    return directions[d]
}
```

Comment: Complete code +1. A simpler version https://play.golang.org/p/j8BN7sLsmjt.